# Trying to fix my class notes

Tags: c++

I need help trying to get this to run properly. The program is suppose to show the array numbers and the number 78 for one of the indexes. I don't get any compiler errors when trying to run it, but it closes out of the program instantly.

```
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector (int number_of_elements);  
    int num;
    int *p;
};

int main()
{
    Vector va(10);

    va.p = new int[va.num];

    for (int i = 0; i < va.num; i++)
    {
        va.p[i]=i;

        for (int i = 0; i < va.num; i++)
        {
            cout << va.p[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    Vector vb(va); 


    vb.p[0] = 78;  //if you switch these 3 lines with the 3 above 78 gets printed out everyline
    for (int i = 0; i < vb.num; i++)
    {
        cout << vb.p[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Vector::Vector(int number_of_elements)
{
    num = number_of_elements;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's closing the program instantly because the program finished too fast. Why not adding a readkey or something similar at the end of main(), so the program waits for a keypress, so you have time to see the result?

Comment: I can't see any glaring bugs but (i) why not initialise the data buffer `p` in the constructor, (ii) `delete` any memory allocated in a destructor, (iii) be aware that `vb(va)` will only take a shallow copy of `va`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code.

First as @Pavlin have stated add a keypress to stop the console termination.

You have a memory leak. You have

```
 va.p = new int[va.num];
 you have to delete it like this
 delete[] va.p
```

The second problem is here :

```
 Vector vb(va);
```

This statement creates an object from an existing object. It uses a special function called the copy constructor. Since you have memory allocated dynamically you have to provide you own copy constructor like this:

```
Vector(const& Vector tmp) { // code here);
```

otherwise it copies the pointer rather than values. Its a shallow copy but you need a deep copy  instead,

And it is highly adviced that when you use pointers inside a class add a destructor to delete allocated memory.